# C++ program can not be compiled

Tags: c++, ubuntu, gcc

I have just started learning c++. When i compile the following code using GCC version: **gcc (Ubuntu 5.2.1-22ubuntu2) 5.2.1 20151010**
i get this errors:

gcc tst.cpp -o mytst

```
/tmp/ccGA15Qf.o: In function `main':
tst.cpp:(.text+0xa): undefined reference to `std::cout'
tst.cpp:(.text+0xf): undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*)'
tst.cpp:(.text+0x19): undefined reference to `std::cout'
tst.cpp:(.text+0x1e): undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*)'
/tmp/ccGA15Qf.o: In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)':
tst.cpp:(.text+0x4c): undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::Init()'
tst.cpp:(.text+0x5b): undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::~Init()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

and here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main ()
{
  std::cout << "Hello World! ";
  std::cout << "I'm a C++ program";
}
```

What is going wrong?

Comment: @Satya Not a pro tip.

Comment: OP did not miss any `std::` and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-in-c-considered-bad-practice).

Comment: @Satya Nothing, just remove the comment. It is totally nonsensical.

Comment: @Satya [Why is “using namespace std” in C++ considered bad practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/995714)

Comment: Already removed my comment friends. Please accept my apologies.

Comment: @Satya Your nonsensical comment is still there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use g++, not gcc for compiling c++ files

Answer (score 0):

'g++ test.cpp -o test' solved the problem

Comment: While this is trivial, it isn't trivial to anyone asking the question. A bit of a why explanation is needed to make this an answer. One more sentence would do it.